# Kivy TabbedPanel switch_to work inconsistently

Tags: python, kivy

I am writing a code which starts the frontend, runs the backend and then loads the frontend. The frontend consists of TabbedPanel, and the currently displayed tab may be change by backend.

Here's the MRE:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelHeader


def button(instance):

    instance.parent.parent.switch_to(instance.parent.parent.tab_2)  # accessing TabbedPanel without messing with sending
    # a variable


def backend(frontend):

    # this class represents main backend function. In the result of its execution there might be a need to switch to
    # another tab

    frontend.switch_to(frontend.tab_2)


class MyTabbedPanel(TabbedPanel):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__()
        self.tab_1 = TabbedPanelHeader()
        self.tab_2 = TabbedPanelHeader()
        self.tab_1.content = Button(text='Tab 1')
        self.tab_1.content.bind(on_release=button)
        self.tab_2.content = Label(text='Tab 2')
        self.add_widget(self.tab_1)
        self.add_widget(self.tab_2)


class Application(App):

    def build(self):
        frontend = MyTabbedPanel()
        backend(frontend)
        return frontend


Application().run()
```

The button, which I have added to compare, to switch from tab 1 to tab 2 works just fine, however, the auto swith when starting the app does not work.

What is the problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time that you're calling `backend`, there is no root widget returned by the `build` method, let alone a tab to switch to.
One way to solve this, is to schedule the call to the `backend` for after the `build` ends, using the [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) module.

```py
    def build(self):
        frontend = MyTabbedPanel()
        # backend(frontend)
        from functools import partial
        from kivy.clock import Clock
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(backend, frontend))
        return frontend
```

You also have to add an `args` argument to the `backend` method, because [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) sends a `dt` value:
`def backend(frontend, *args):`